# Extract dplyr tbl and create vector where column 1 = column 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In order to map colours to group, I am using the `scale_colour_manual(values = c("G1" = "grey", ...))` function of the `{ggplot2}`package.

I have a main tibble with data where you can find groups, and I would like to highlight a specific group. Here G3 is highlighted, however this is not necessarily the case for all plots I want to generate.

Here is some sample data:

```
groups <- as_tibble(c("G1", "G2", "G3"))
colours <- as_tibble(c("grey", "grey", "purple"))
```

I then pull the vectors, but I don't know how to get the result mentioned above (`values = c("G1" = "grey", ...)`)

```
groups_vec <- groups %>% pull()
colours_vec <- colours %>% pull()
myvalues <- c(groups_vec = colours_vec)

# this code returns the following
groups_vec1 groups_vec2 groups_vec3 
     "grey"      "grey"    "purple"
```

whereas I expect the following result:

```
c("G1" = "grey", "G2" = "grey", "G3" = "purple")

      G1       G2       G3 
  "grey"   "grey" "purple"
```

I can't find the right words to describe my problem, hope the example is clear enough.

Comment: Please provide your sample data with `dput()` and desired output

Answer (score 0):

The following should help.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# simulate some data
some_data <- tibble(
  GROUPS = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3","Group4"), 
  VALUES = c(2,5,9,3), 
  COL = c("grey","grey","lightblue","grey")
)
# plot
ggplot(data = some_data) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = GROUPS, y = VALUES, fill = COL)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "green"))
```

Try to understand how the variable "COL" and the "values" in scale_fill_manual() work together.

EDITED ANSWER

You did not provide a reproducible example. Thus, the answer might not be exactly what you are fishing for. But I truly hope the following will help you understand how `{ggplot}` works with `aesthetics` and how you can control the way these aesthetics are presented.

I build the example on a simple `geom_col()`. You might have another use-case. But the principle should be transferable to all `geoms`. Just note that for some geoms you need to use `color` instead of `fill`.

P.S. I also recommend to use a single data-frame for your plot. There is no need to keep every variable in a separate tibble. Just add a column with the color-flag you want to use. This might simplify your code ... and the number of objects you use.

Let's start with a simple plot of what we have.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# simulate some data
some_data <- tibble(
  GROUPS = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3","Group4"), 
  VALUES = c(2,5,9,3), 
  COL = c("grey","grey","purple","grey")
)

# understand how ggplot uses "categories" based on COL variable
# without specification ggplot uses the default colors for 2 different "categories", i.e. grey and purple

p <- ggplot(data = some_data) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = GROUPS, y = VALUES, fill = COL))

p
```

Please note that {ggplot} uses the default colors in a specific sequence (as they come). We come to this back later, as this is the sequence you will need to control. To make this more prominent, recode your colors, e.g. instead of `purple` set it to `highlight` (or `yes`,`Y`). The characters are only a "category" for {ggplot}. The actual value is of secondary order (while we humans assign meaning to something like "green" or "purple").
This yields:

[image]

Next look into assigning colors. Key take away, the sequence of your color specification matters!

```
p1 <- p + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "purple")) +
  labs(subtitle = "order of categories [grey, purple]")

p2 <- p + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("purple", "grey")) +
  labs(subtitle = "order of categories [purple, grey]")

library(patchwork)  # for demo purposes we plot both graphs side by side
p1 + p2
```

[image]

You did not provide a reproducible example. Thus, let's emulate your `function f()` by assigning a new color based on a value. (Your function might be more complex, but I understand it will give you a flag for the color).

```
# some operation that can happen in a function to change the color coding
# e.g. we pick the value 5
some_data2 <- some_data %>% 
  mutate(COL = case_when(
    between(VALUES, 4,6) ~ "purple"
    ,TRUE ~ "grey"
  ))

# note - now we have a vector of values for each "row" (aka group) in your dataframe
color_vec <- c("grey", "yellow", "grey", "purple")

some_data2 <- some_data2 %>% mutate(COL2 = color_vec)
```

Have a look at the tibble:

```
some_data2
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  GROUPS VALUES COL    COL2  
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
1 Group1      2 grey   grey  
2 Group2      5 purple yellow
3 Group3      9 grey   grey  
4 Group4      3 grey   purple
```

Let's plot this tibble using `aesthetic fill` for column `COL` and set our color-vector as the desired sequence in `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
some_data2 %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = GROUPS, y = VALUES, fill = COL)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_vec)
```

[image]

OOOOOPS!?! what happened here?
Again. try to understand color assigment and number of colors in your plot (aka "categories").

Let's now use our "new" color column, i.e. `COL2`.

```
some_data2 %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = GROUPS, y = VALUES, fill = COL2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_vec)
```

[image]

Try to work out why this also not works.

What you probably want is a sequence of colors dependent on the values you want to highlight. Your example does not explicitly mention how you construct this. Above provides you a pointer how to handle this with a simple `highlight` vs `no-highlight` (2 categories). But you can obviously define more colors like in the following example. In the following example, we make use of the fact that our column `COL2` uses the `target colors` based on your function. Please note that you could define the categories (aka `breaks` different from the color values - think factor label and level).

```
# note - we define values for the different "categories" that we expect
# in this example now 3 (order matters - c.f. above!)
categories <- some_data2$COL2       
color_vec2 <- some_data2$COL2     # if you use flags that are different from colors you can define them here

some_data2 %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = GROUPS, y = VALUES, fill = COL2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
  # breaks sets the sequence of your categories
       breaks = categories
  # values are the colors you want to use
     , values = color_vec2)
```

[image]

You can use - for geom_col() - the fill aesthetic to have it colored in - what I call here - "categories".
With `scale_fill_manual()`, you control the color sequence of these categories. You may want to create this vector based on the order of colors.

Comment: If I understand your example, all values other than "grey" will be filled with  "green". 
I'm looking to add it to a function, which means I don't know which group will be highlighted. For that reason, this solution doesn't fit. I'll clarify my question though, thx !

Comment: I hope the revised answer gets you there, DanielMc. As mentioned, try to write the function in such a way that the "to-highlight" row(s) get a flag (strictly speaking there is no need to assign the color in the function). Use the number of (different) flags (aka categories) to define your color-vector. Make sure to control the sequence, if you opt for multiple flags/colors. Good luck!